# What permissions required to solve BigQuery "An error occurred while enabling the Scheduled Queries API." problem

Tags: google-bigquery

I can't enable scheduled queries in Bigquery.
When I click,
Schedule > Enable Scheduled Queries > Enable API,
every time it says "An error occurred while enabling the Scheduled Queries API." and it cannot be enabled.

I was assigned these 2 roles, but it still error.
・BigQuery data editor
・BigQuery job user
are assigned.
Could you tell me what permissions and settings are required to enable scheduled queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [BigQuery documentation:](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries)

To schedule a query, you need the following IAM permissions:

- bigquery.transfers.update OR (bigquery.jobs.create AND bigquery.transfers.get)

To run a scheduled query, you need following permissions on the target dataset.

- bigquery.jobs.create
- bigquery.datasets.update

To modify a scheduled query, you need the following IAM permissions:

- bigquery.jobs.create
- bigquery.transfers.update

To delete a scheduled query, you need the following IAM permissions:

- bigquery.transfers.update